# Oracle dbms_xmldom.ISNULL what's the difference in 10G and 11G?

Tags: xml, oracle, plsql, database, isnull

For the code below, in Oracle 10g, it says the node is empty, in 11g, it's not empty. There is a newline character between in side . If there is a space inside, the result is the same for both version. Once nothing inside, both two version will not have the output.  Why does this happen ?

```
DECLARE
   v_doc                dbms_xmldom.DOMDocument;
   v_elem               dbms_xmldom.DOMElement;
   v_nelem              dbms_xmldom.DOMNode;    
BEGIN
   -- create the DOMDocument
   v_doc := dbms_xmldom.newDOMDocument(xmlType('<XMLDATA>
                         </XMLDATA>'));
   v_nelem := DBMS_XMLDOM.MAKENODE(v_doc);
   v_nelem := DBMS_XSLPROCESSOR.SELECTSINGLENODE(v_nelem,'XMLDATA/text()');
   IF NOT(dbms_xmldom.ISNULL(v_nelem)) THEN      
      DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('The node is not empty');
   END IF; 
END;
/
```